# カスタムセルに配置したボタンのIBAction関数が呼ばれない。

Tags: swift, ios

・やりたいこと
　カスタムセルに配置したボタンが押下されたときに処理（画像の差し替え）をしたい

・問題点
　ボタンを押下してもIBActionでリンクしたアクション関数が呼ばれません。

・CustomCell.xib / CustomCell.swift といったファイルを用意して、
　CustomCell.xibにボタンを配置していて、そのボタンから、
　IBActionの関数をCustomCell.swiftに記述しています。
・インスペクタで見てみると、ちゃんとリンクは張られています。
・CustomCell.xib のオーナーは、CustomCell.swift になっています。

「ここを確認した方がいい」、「こうゆう処理に変えた方が良い」など
アドバイスありましたら、教えて頂けないでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 実際のコードが提示されていないと回答が付きづらいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄にご指摘があるように、質問文の現状では、「いやあ、それできるはずだよ？実際やってみたら、できたよ？」という反応しか返ってこないでしょう。そのような内容では、回答にならないので、結果回答がつかないということになるしかありません。
私も、ネット上の情報（「xib tableviewcell」などのキーワードで検索した結果）をもとにして、Xcodeのプロジェクトを作ってみて、セル上のボタンをタップして、IBActionに設定したメソッドを実行することができました。しかし、実のところこれといった支障なく、結果が得られたわけではありません。サイトに載っている手順どおりにしたのに、ボタンを押しても無反応という結果が、何度も続いたことは事実です。
ネット上の情報のうち、成功事例は、次のようなものです。
それはXIBファイルの作り方です。XcodeのFileメニュー、Newから、直接XIBファイルを作るのではなく、Cocoa touchクラスファイルの作成のオプションとして、XIBファイルを作ります。（下図参照。Also create XIB fileにチェックを入れ、クラスファイルを新規作成します。）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この方法で、XIBファイルを作成すると、XIBの諸設定が、プリセットされた状態で保存されるので、設定ミス、設定忘れを予防できます。